# Qt revert my changes in ui file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with my ui_visualalgorithm.h file.

ui_visualalgorithm has such includes:

```
#include "codeeditor.h"
#include "visualalgorithmsceneview.h"
...
```

But recently i changed my codeeditor.h and visualalgorithmsceneview.h locations.

So i rewrited includes like this:

```
#include "AppElements/CodeEdit/codeeditor.h"
#include "AppElements/visualgraphsceneview.h"
...
```

Everything was fine until i changed my visualalgorithm form.

After building the project,Qt tells me that my ui_visualalgorithm file has changed outside of QT Creator. If I agree to reload my file,I have the same includes,which I had:

```
#include "codeeditor.h"
#include "visualalgorithmsceneview.h"
...
```

If I deny reloading, my changes to visualalgorithm form don't save.
So how can I change this includes and save my changes to the form?

---

The issue has been resolved by changing the visualalgorithm.ui file.

Instead of

```
 <header>codeeditor.h</header>
```

I wrote

```
 <header>AppElements/CodeEdit/codeeditor.h</header>
```

After that ui_visualalgorithm.h is generated correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is a generated file. It is generated at build time, so any changes you make to it are eventually futile.

Instead, you have to take it to the root of the problem: The XML-based .ui file. You can edit that file in an editor outside of Qt Creator and it will work. However, you can also fix the header locations in the form editor, using the **Promoted Widgets** dialog.